# NSMutableArray sorting and displaying in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, sorting, nsmutablearray, uniqueidentifier, uitableviewsectionheader

I need to show a grouped tableview from the below data. I need to categorise the below array based on **"account_type"**.

For Eg: I need to show Table Section Heading "Savings" and list all savings type accounts, then similarly get Unique account types and gave that as section header and account numbers in table rows. I am able to get section headers using NSSet, but how to get row counts and display it in a UITableView.

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7f8ef1e8b790>(
{
"account_no" = 123;
"account_type" = Savings;
},
{
"account_no" = 123456;
"account_type" = Savings;
},
{
"account_no" = 00000316;
"account_type" = "DPN STAFF NON EMI";
},
{
"account_no" = 1000000552;
"account_type" = "DPN STAFF EMI LOANS";
})
```

I need to display the above data in UITableView like

**section 0 --- Savings**

Row 1 - 123

Row 2 - 123456

**section 1 ---> DPN STAFF NON EMI**

Row 1 - 00000316

Thanks,

AKC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of NSDictionary also. The below code worked perfectly.

```
if([arrySelectedDetails count] >0){

        grouped = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:arrySelectedAcctDetails.count];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in arrySelectedDetails) {
            id key = [dict valueForKey:@"type"];

            NSMutableArray *tmp = [grouped objectForKey:key];
            if (tmp == nil) {
                tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [grouped setObject:tmp forKey:key];

            }
            [tmp addObject:dict];

        }


        typeArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for(NSDictionary *groupId in arrySelectedDetails){

            if(!([typeArray count]>0)){
                [typeArray addObject:[groupId valueForKey:@"type"]];

            }
            else if (![typeArray containsObject:[groupId valueForKey:@"type"]]) {
                [typeArray addObject:[groupId valueForKey:@"type"]];

            }

        }
    }
```

Then for UITableView Delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [typeArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [grouped[[typeArray objectAtIndex:section]] count]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try the below code:**

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSArray *groups = [arrySelectedAcctDetails valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.account_type"];

NSLog(@"%@", groups);

for (NSString *groupId in groups)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [entry setObject:groupId forKey:@"account_type"];

    NSArray *groupNames = [arrySelectedAcctDetails filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"account_type = %@", groupId]];

  for (int i = 0; i < groupNames.count; i++)
  {
   NSString *name = [[groupNames objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"account_no"];
  [entry setObject:name forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"account_no%d", i + 1]];
  }
            [resultArray addObject:entry];
}

 NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);
```

**Output:**

```
{
        "account_no1" = 00000316;
        "account_type" = "DPN STAFF  NON EMI";
    },
        {
        "account_no1" = 123;
        "account_no2" = 123456;
        "account_type" = Savings;
    },
```

Comment: Hi Abin, Thanks for the code. It worked perfectly. But how to display it as section header and row in a UITableView?